# getting split weeks in method to get list of months

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using this method to get a list of week start from my data.
However, at the end of the month a week could be a split between 2 months
however i am having a hard time using my method to check the split weeks in my method to get the months

**Method to get list of Months**

```
var monthlist = data.Select(x => new { wkdate =  x.WKENDstart }).OrderBy(y => y.wkdate).Select(m => new
        {
            monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Method to check if its a split week**

```
public static bool isSplitWeek(System.DateTime Enddate, System.DateTime Startdate)
{
    bool isSameMonth = (Enddate.Month == Startdate.Month) ? true : false;

    return !isSameMonth ? true : false;

}
```

Im basically trying to use an if where it say x.WKENDstart, that way i get both months if a week starts in one month and ends in another.

Comment: I'm not sure about the upvoters, but I for my part have very little idea what you're asking...

Comment: !isSameMonth ? true : false; is dangerous, is hard to read after a couple of days

Comment: basically im trying to say ok if this 2/26/2012 is a split week, bring me back Feb. and March not just Febuary

Comment: I agree with @lvo return !isSameMonth ? true : false; is the same thing as return !isSameMonth; but the second is more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deciding on how i could approach this issue i decided to use a .WHERE clause and a .Union
By doing this i was able to handle normal weeks in one section and split weeks in another and just union them together. The key to the issue was to use the where clause.

```
 var monthlist1 =                
    data.Select(x => new { wkdate = x.WKENDDATE }).OrderBy(y => y.wkdate).Where(l=> ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(l.wkdate,l.wkdate.AddDays(6)) != true)
    .Select(m => new{monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))})
    .Distinct()            
    .ToList();

  var monthlist2 = 
     data.Select(x => new { wkdate = x.WKENDDATE.AddDays(6) }).OrderBy(y => y.wkdate).Where(l=> ExportHelper.isSplitWeek(l.wkdate.AddDays(-6),l.wkdate) == true).Select(m => new
    {monthname = m.wkdate.ToString("MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))}) 
    .Distinct()            
    .ToList();

  var monthlist = monthlist2.Union(monthlist1)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be over thinking this method:

```
public static bool isSplitWeek(System.DateTime Enddate, System.DateTime Startdate)
{
    return Enddate.Month != Startdate.Month;
}
```

---

So perhaps something like:

```
public static IList<string> TransformDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<string> months = new List<string>
    {
        start.ToString("MMM yyyy", 
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
    };

    if (isSplitWeek(start, end))
    {
        months.Add(end.ToString("MMM yyyy", 
                CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
    }

    return months;
}
```

...

```
var monthlist = data
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        start =  x.WKENDstart,
        end = x.WKENDstart.AddDays(6)
    })
    .OrderBy(y => y.start )
    .Select(m => new
    {
        monthname = TransformDates(m.start, m.end) // IList<string> 
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is definitely clearer, but I don't think that will solve his problem, since it does exactly the same as the OP's method.

Comment: thanks for simplifying the method however how could i use it in my linq method

Comment: @bugz, post your object/class that has `WKENDstart` and I'll update this answer.

Comment: this is good however i dont want the date to come up as feb - mar, i just wanted a list of months is it possible where i can still use this method??

Comment: Ok, so now TransformDates takes a start and end. It will always return the Start month. If and only if the week is spilt will it append the end month. What do you think?